# Text field spanning multiple vertical sections

Tags: crystal-reports

[image]

Can "OpeningRemark" cross into the next section?

Answer (score 1):

Put "OpeningRemark" in its own section above its current place, then select `Underlay Following Sections` in the section expert. And make sure the "OpeningRemark" can grow vertically.